# How to get images/attachments sent by user from telegram bot through Dialog Flow v2?

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot

I've already read [How to get images/attachments sent by user from Facebook messenger bot through Dialog Flow (API.AI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877394/how-to-get-images-attachments-sent-by-user-from-facebook-messenger-bot-through-d)

Seems like FACEBOOK_MEDIA dosent exists anymore? I guess that somethings like exist also for telegram but I didnt find events triggered when a users send an image/photos to my telegram bot.

Any solutions to handle this problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can still add FACEBOOK_MEDIA event in your intent's configuration. Unfortunately Messenger integration seems to be the only one which supports event for receiving files.

Comment: In Dialogflow, FACEBOOK_MEDIA event doesn't appear in the drop down. Only FACEBOOK_WELCOME is shown. Could you please clarify how to still add FACEBOOK_MEDIA event? Thanks

Comment: Solved! - Realised that I could just type that event, and it worked :)